# Can Fabric be used to log events from the backend?

Tags: events, google-fabric

We're using Fabric for our mobile apps and now we'd like to also log some events and data from the backend directly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's not currently possible but something interesting for us to consider. All events need to be called via the device.